# SQL query using variable in the where clause for exclusions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, dynamic-sql

I am using dbWarden (https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dbwarden-a-free-sql-server-monitoring-package-3) for SQL monitoring and would like for certain procs to be excluded from the "long running queries" job based on an exclusion list table. I am trying to list a bunch of SQL_TEXT strings in a table that should be excluded from my query in the WHERE clause.

The portion of the proc I am editing looks like this:

```
DECLARE @exclusions NVARCHAR (MAX);
SELECT @exclusions = COALESCE(@exclusions + '%''' +  ' and SQL_TEXT not like ''%' + SQL_TEXT , SQL_TEXT) FROM LongRunningQueriesExclusions 

    
    
    
SELECT * FROM QUERYHISTORY
                WHERE RunTime >= 10
                AND [DBName] NOT IN (SELECT [DBName] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT FROM [DBATools].dbo.DatabaseSettings WHERE LongQueryAlerts = 0)
                AND Formatted_SQL_Text NOT LIKE '%BACKUP DATABASE%'
                AND Formatted_SQL_Text NOT LIKE '%RESTORE VERIFYONLY%'
                AND Formatted_SQL_Text NOT LIKE '%ALTER INDEX%'
                AND Formatted_SQL_Text NOT LIKE '%DECLARE @BlobEater%'
                AND Formatted_SQL_Text NOT LIKE '%DBCC%'
                AND Formatted_SQL_Text NOT LIKE '%FETCH API_CURSOR%'
                AND Formatted_SQL_Text NOT LIKE '%WAITFOR(RECEIVE%'
                -- MY ADDITION ------------------------------------------------------
                AND SQL_TEXT not LIKE  '''%' + @exclusions + '%'''
```

My exclusions table has the following procs I want to exclude:
[LongRunningQueriesExclusions Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnC2Y.png)

When printing the @exclusions variable it returns:
`SP_testProc%' and SQL_TEXT not like '%SP_AnotherTestProc%' and SQL_TEXT not like '%SP_OneMoreTest`

The query returns what I expect when replacing the variable with the printed text but does not work with the variable itself.

Is there a way to include my exclusions list with the wildcards in the WHERE clause of my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to build this statement dynamically, you can just reference your exclusions table from the main query directly and use `NOT EXISTS` to remove records with SQL text that contains values from there. e.g.

```
AND NOT EXISTS
    (   SELECT  1
        FROM    LongRunningQueriesExclusions AS exc
        WHERE   QUERYHISTORY.SQL_TEXT LIKE CONCAT('%', exc.SQL_TEXT , '%')
    );
```

As an aside, you should not use variable assignment to concatenate strings, [the behaviour is unreliable and undocumented](https://marc.durdin.net/2015/07/concatenating-strings-in-sql-server-or-undefined-behaviour-by-design/) you should use [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), e.g.

```
DECLARE @exclusions NVARCHAR (MAX);
SELECT @exclusions = STRING_AGG(' SQL_TEXT not like ''%' + SQL_TEXT + '%''', ' AND ') 
FROM LongRunningQueriesExclusions;
```